# SharePoint Pictures

Tags: sharepoint, image

Is There an easier way to have pictures on the sharepoint site? I only one way to do this but I want to find another way if its faster and easier for users to use.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into Telerik's FREE Radeditor for MOSS.

P.S. Belongs on superuser.

Comment: I know that you have to be the super user to upload the pictures but i want to know if there is a better way to get charts and pictures on SharePoint

Comment: He meant 'superuser' the other site that the stackoverflow guys have for questions more related to settings/how to use than programming itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use this in all cases as it depends on user permissions, how much you trust your users, and if your users are internal and have access to your network.

But, with that said...

The fastest, easiest way I know how to load pictures into a Picture Library is to go to the Library, select Actions > Open with Windows Explorer, and drag images into Windows Explorer, which populates the Library.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to be fast.

If you want to be fast in uploading all the files, upload them using the explorer view into your picture library.

If you want to be fast in editing content, then there really is only one option : use SharePoint 2010 as adding pictures has become as easy as adding pictures in a Word document. Insert picture, specify which file of the filesystem you want and select a picture library in which the picture will be automatically uploaded.